# My cat have respiratory infection and it cant eat? it want to eat but cat smell it?

Tags: cats, feeding

My cat has this infection and when it sees food it go for it (it doesn't refuse the idea ) but it tries to smell it and then Nothing .. It have been 4 day till now .. anybody tell me what to do t make it through this period until the infection and the antibiotic course end and get to be effective  .. and is ther any ways to make it eat or to get its nose cleaned

Comment: Consult your vet. There is no other answer.